# What is the distribution of the product between a continuous (Exponential) and a discrete (Bernoulli) random variables?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

If you have $X$ distributed as a $\mathrm{Bernoulli}(p)$ and $Y$ as a $\mathrm{Exponential}(\lambda)$ find $Z=XY$.

I tried doing it with the MFG i.e. $$E[e^{tZ}]=E[e^{tXY}]=E[E[e^{tXY}|_{X=x}]=E[E[e^{txY}]|_{X=x}]$$ but this is where I got stuck, I don´t know if this is the proper way to solve this, I would appreciate a step-by-step explanation.

Answer (score 0):

$E[e^{tXY}]=(1-p)E[e^{tY \times 0}] + pE[e^{tY \times 1}] =(1-p)E[1] + pE[e^{tY}]$. 
Does that help?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what to do with this result. I did this and lead me to nowhere: $$=(1-p)+p(\frac{\lambda}{\lambda-t})$$ $$=1-p(\frac{t}{\lambda-t})$$ $$=\frac{\lambda-t(p+1)}{\lambda-t}$$, Most probably I'm worng, but any comments would be appreciated.

Comment: I think your first line is the most useful. There maybe a better way of doing this but you now have to guess a f(z) that will give you this mgf. Split it into f(z) = something when z=0 and $f(z)=$ something else when z>0.

Comment: Well, the first line looks like the MFG of a $\mathrm{Bernoulli}$ but instead of $e^t$ we have $\frac{\lambda}{\lambda - t}$. Am I going the right direction?

Comment: Check the details but something like $f(z)=(1-p)$ when z=0 and $f(z)=p \lambda e^{-\lambda z}$ when z>0.

Comment: That looks like you just gave me the answer! :D
But the thing is, this isn't homework or something like that, I just came across with this, and catched my attention so I really want to understand the logic and theory behind this.
And by now it look something like:

Comment: $$E[e^{tZ}]=E[e^{tXY}]=E[E[e^{tYX}]|_{X=0,1}]=\begin{cases} (1-p)E[1] & \text{if }E[E[e^{tYX}]|_{X=0}] \\pE[e^{tY}] & \text{if }E[E[e^{tYX}]|_{X=1}]
\end{cases}$$ Hence $$Z \sim \begin{cases} 1-p & \text{if} \ \ z=0 \\ p\lambda e^{-\lambda x} & \text{if} \ \ z>0\end{cases}$$ So far it makes sence but I'm really struggling to understand this: What is the relation with the MGF over the distribution so we can make this assertion? Sorry for the troubles, but I really appreciate this.